# How to pass `None` Batch Size to tensorflow dynamic rnn?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a `CNN+LSTM+CTC` model for word recognition. 
Initially I have an image, I am converting the features extracted using  `CNN` on word image and building a sequence of features which I am passing as sequential data to `RNN`. 
Follwing is how I am converting the features to sequential data: 
`[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3]] -> [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]` 
Where `a,b,c` are 3 features extracted using `CNN`. 
Presently I can pass a constant `batch_size` to the model `common.BATCH_SIZE`, but what I want is to be able to pass variable `batch_size` to the model.
How can this be done ?

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [common.BATCH_SIZE, common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[1], common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[0], 1])
# Here we use sparse_placeholder that will generate a
# SparseTensor required by ctc_loss op.
targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)

# 1d array of size [batch_size]
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [common.BATCH_SIZE])

model = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, 64, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='c1')
model = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(model, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='m1')
model = tf.layers.conv2d(model, 128,(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='c2')
model = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(model, (3,3),strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='m2')
model = tf.transpose(model, [3,0,1,2])
shape = model.get_shape().as_list()
model = tf.reshape(model, [shape[0],-1,shape[2]*shape[3]])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(common.num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=0.5, output_keep_prob=0.5)
stack = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*common.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, model, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32,time_major=True)
```

UPDATE:

```
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, None, name='batch_size')

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[1], common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[0], 1])
# Here we use sparse_placeholder that will generate a
# SparseTensor required by ctc_loss op.
targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)

# 1d array of size [batch_size]
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])

model = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, 64, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='c1')
model = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(model, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='m1')
model = tf.layers.conv2d(model, 128,(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='c2')
model = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(model, (3,3),strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='m2')
model = tf.transpose(model, [3,0,1,2])
shape = model.get_shape().as_list()
model = tf.reshape(model, [shape[0],-1,shape[2]*shape[3]])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(common.num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=0.5, output_keep_prob=0.5)
stack = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*common.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, model, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32,time_major=True)
```

I am getting error as below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm_and_ctc_ocr_train.py", line 203, in <module>
    train()
  File "lstm_and_ctc_ocr_train.py", line 77, in train
    logits, inputs, targets, seq_len, batch_size = model.get_train_model()
  File "/home/himanshu/learning-tf/tf/code/tensorflow_lstm_ctc_ocr/model.py", line 20, in get_train_model
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[1], common.OUTPUT_SHAPE[0], 1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 705, in apply_op
    attr_value.shape.CopyFrom(_MakeShape(value, key))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 198, in _MakeShape
    return tensor_shape.as_shape(v).as_proto()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 798, in as_shape
    return TensorShape(shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 434, in __init__
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 376, in as_dimension
    return Dimension(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 32, in __init__
    self._value = int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass `batch_size` to dynamic RNN as a placeholder. In my experience, the only headache you might experience is if you don't specify its shape in advance, so you should pass [] to make things work, something like this:

batchsize = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], name='batchsize')

and then feed its value during sess.run() in the usual way. This works well for me while training on a large batch size, but then generating with batch of 1.

But strictly speaking, you don't even need to specify batch size for `dynamic_rnn` specifically, do you? You need it if you use `MultiRNNCell` to get zero state, but I don't see you doing that in your code...

*** UPDATE:

As discussed in the comment, your problem seems to have nothing to do with `dynamic_rnn` and more to do with the fact that you are using a placeholder `inputs` to specify the shape of another placeholder `seq_len`. Here's the code that reproduces the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, None, name='a')
b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [a, 5], name='b')
c = b * 5

with tf.Session() as sess:
    C = sess.run(c, feed_dict={a:1, b:[[1,2,3,4,5]]})
```

And here's the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Before getting to the headache of `dynamic_rnn`, I would recommend finding a way around this, either by changing your code or by asking a separate question on how to fudge it with placeholders.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I am still getting the error as mentioned in updated question

Comment: The reason I had to put a fixed `batch_size` is because I am converting image data to sequential data, so for that I am doing `model = tf.reshape(model, [shape[0],-1,shape[2]*shape[3]])` , so if I am putting `None` in `batch_size` I am getting something as you can't multiply integer with None

Comment: Looking at your updated post and the error stack, I think the problem has nothing to do with dynamic_rnn. I think the problem is that you are providing a placeholder (inputs) in the specification of the shape of another placeholder (seq_len). I will update my answer to show you the minimum code that can reproduce this error. I'm not sure how to get around it, maybe you can somehow change the logic of your code to feed that value otherwise. It would probably be best to ask a separate question specifically for that -- you will be more likely to get an answer. Check my updated answer for the code